# Trouble while installing cupy on Windows 10 with pip

Tags: python, cuda, nvidia, cupy

I want to install CuPy but I get this error. I have MX150 Graphics card which supports CUDA. I have installed the CUDA development kit and cuDNN:

Here are my system specs

- i5-8250U
- 8GB Ram
- Nvidia GeForce MX150

My Python version is 3.7.8

```
pip install cupy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\micha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yra_27m9\\cupy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yra_27m9\\cupy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-e77cwad4'
         cwd: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yra_27m9\cupy\
    Complete output (48 lines):
    Options: {'package_name': 'cupy', 'long_description': None, 'wheel_libs': [], 'wheel_includes': [], 'no_rpath': False, 'profile': False, 'linetrace': False, 'annotate': False, 'no_cuda': False, 'use_hip': False}
    **************************************************
    *** WARNING: nvcc path != CUDA_PATH
    *** WARNING: nvcc path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
    *** WARNING: CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
    **************************************************

    -------- Configuring Module: cuda --------
    Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ************************************************************
    * CuPy Configuration Summary                               *
    ************************************************************

    Build Environment:
      Include directories: []
      Library directories: []
      nvcc command       : (not found)

    Environment Variables:
      CFLAGS          : (none)
      LDFLAGS         : (none)
      LIBRARY_PATH    : (none)
      CUDA_PATH       : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
      NVTOOLSEXT_PATH : (none)
      NVCC            : (none)
      ROCM_HOME       : (none)

    Modules:
      cuda      : No
        -> Include files not found: ['cublas_v2.h', 'cuda.h', 'cuda_profiler_api.h', 'cuda_runtime.h', 'cufft.h', 'curand.h', 'cusparse.h', 'nvrtc.h']
        -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.

    ERROR: CUDA could not be found on your system.
    Please refer to the Installation Guide for details:
    https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html

    ************************************************************

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yra_27m9\cupy\setup.py", line 128, in <module>
        ext_modules = cupy_setup_build.get_ext_modules()
      File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yra_27m9\cupy\cupy_setup_build.py", line 744, in get_ext_modules
        extensions = make_extensions(arg_options, compiler, use_cython)
      File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yra_27m9\cupy\cupy_setup_build.py", line 492, in make_extensions
        raise Exception('Your CUDA environment is invalid. '
    Exception: Your CUDA environment is invalid. Please check above error log.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download Visual Studio C++

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Do I need to install Visual Studio Completely Cause I don't see anything that matches Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 Thank You

Comment: it's embeded in visual studio code just download the community version must work perfectly

Comment: Thanks will try now

Comment: Nope didn't seem to work. Here's the link to complete logfile https://pastebin.com/Nm3dqxu6

Comment: take a look at this one here is all build tools for visual studio include C++ 


https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

Comment: I downloaded that also

Comment: so you're running into some big issue some you have to install the toolkit first as documentated here is the link 

https://pypi.org/project/cupy-cuda102/

then retry to install it again see how it works

Comment: I think this also will work
```
pip install cupy-cuda101
```

Comment: Ok using `pip install cupy-cuda101` solved the problem